# Error: Field createdAt: Couldn't find type DateTime in any of the schemas

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have backend of my app on graphql/prisma and i need to create a field - createdAt: DateTime! @createdAtin in datamodal.prisma for the keeping creating dates on a server. According official documents - https://www.prisma.io/docs/1.34/datamodel-and-migrations/datamodel-MYSQL-knul/. But i can not to start a server because have Error: Field createdAt: Couldn't find type DateTime in any of the schemas. Can somebody explain me what i'm doing wrong?

datamodel.prisma

```
type Channel {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  title: String!
  cover: String!
  stars: Int
  creator: User! @relation(name: "ChannelToUser", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  topics: [Topic!]! @relation(name: "TopicToChannel", onDelete: CASCADE)
}

type Message {
  id: ID! @id
  text: String!
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  creator: User! @relation(name: "MessageToUser", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  topic: Topic! @relation(name: "MessageToTopic", onDelete: SET_NULL)
}

type Topic {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  title: String!
  stars: Int
  avatar: String!
  creator: User! @relation(name: "TopicToUser", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  channel: Channel! @relation(name: "TopicToChannel", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  messages: [Message!]! @relation(name: "MessageToTopic", onDelete: CASCADE)
}


type RefreshToken {
  id: ID! @id
  token: String!
  owner: User! @relation(name: "RefreshTokenToUser", onDelete: SET_NULL)  
}

type User {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  name: String
  email: String
  stars: Int
  phone: String! @unique
  cover: String! 
  avatar: String!
  channels: [Channel!]! @relation(name: "ChannelToUser", onDelete: CASCADE)
  topics: [Topic!]! @relation(name: "TopicToUser", onDelete: CASCADE)
  messages: [Message!]! @relation(name: "MessageToUser", onDelete: CASCADE)
  refreshTokens: [RefreshToken!]! @relation(name: "RefreshTokenToUser", onDelete: CASCADE) 
}
```

Comment: The error is probably not due to your datamodel.prisma. I imagine you have a schema.graphql that defines your types etc. for the api. It is probably here that DateTime is undefined. Set types in here with `createdAt: String!`.

Comment: I solved it with add scalar DateTime to my datamodal.prisma